# Dealing bad date values using MySQLDb

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table that stores information as a set of name-value pairs. Some of the values are supposed to be dates, character encoded like 'YYYY-MM-DD', but I somehow got some bad data into my table. When I try to convert a bad entry to a date from the MySQL command line client I get a null. But when I try to do this using a Python program using MySQLDb it throws an exception like:

> OperationalError(1292, "Incorrect datetime value:
>   'undefined-0-11/30/1971'")

I need to find some way of either programmatically identifying the bad values, or to just have the conversion result in NULL rather than throwing an exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A try-catch block in python should do the trick, where you are catching operational errors. (However, you must make sure you are only getting operational errors because of bad datetime values, and not for other issues as well.) The general logic would look something like this:

```
try:
    <datetime conversion here>
except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
    print "this value is bad!"
```

Comment: Well, the problem is I want my command to succeed for the other rows in the table without having to handle them one by one.